# Python Regular Expression Anychar Including Nothing

Tags: python, regex

In pythons regular expression I am trying to locate something in a table, all works well apart from some of the rows have 2 letters in a table the rest have no data in that field, so I need a regular expression which will match either word characters `\w+` **aswell** as nothing.

an example row that is correctly found

```
</td><td></td><td>
```

an example row that is missed

```
</td><td>JK</td><td>
```

is there a way I can return both rows with the one expression?

Comment: Regexes are a bad choice for solving this problem if you are attempting to get text out of a HTML. Explore BeautifulSoup library. If you intend to stick with regexes, try using `\w*` instead of `\w+`

Comment: What about "<.*>", here .* is greedy and will consume all from the first `<` to the last `>`

Comment: You have stated what you 'want' to match, you also need to state what you "don't want" to match.

Comment: The regex you show doesn't match the strings you give. Is it just a part of a bigger regex? @shaktimaan has the answer in that case.